# UIViewController and XIB question

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

How do I prevent a UIVIewController from loading the xib?

I downloaded an XCode (iPhone) project online, and I want to stop the xib file from loading. The view did load method doesn't have any code in it which deals with xib. How do I force the UIViewController to be loaded from it's viewDidLoad method instead of the xib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite loadview but DO NOT call [super loadview]. Example:

```
-(void)loadView{
    self.view = [UIView new];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

From the Documentation

### loadView

Creates the view that the controller manages.

> You should never call this method
>   directly. The view controller calls this method when the view property
>   is requested but is currently nil. If you create your views manually,
>   you must override this method and use it to create your views. If you
>   use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view
>   controller—that is, you initialize the view using the
>   initWithNibName:bundle: method, set the nibName and nibBundle
>   properties directly, or create both your views and view controller in
>   Interface Builder—then you must not override this method.
>
> The default implementation of this method looks for valid nib
>   information and uses that information to load the associated nib file.
>   If no nib information is specified, the default implementation creates
>   a plain UIView object and makes it the main view.
>
> If you override this method in order to create your views manually,
>   you should do so and assign the root view of your hierarchy to the
>   view property. (The views you create should be unique instances and
>   should not be shared with any other view controller object.) Your
>   custom implementation of this method should not call super.
>
> If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do
>   so in the viewDidLoad method. In iOS 3.0 and later, you should also
>   override the viewDidUnload method to release any references to the
>   view or its contents.

Comment: I see we both have an affection for the color red (:

Comment: lol, it just makes it blatantly clear your code it working correctly when it shows up or not

Comment: I always do that to test if a view is appearing correctly, easy: red is not white.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `initWithNibNameOrNil` method to just `init`.
If that doesn't work, also override the `loadView` method by uncommenting it and setting your view there.

Here's an example:

```
    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.view = myView;
    [myView release];
    }
```

Comment: neither the initWithNibNameOrNil or laodView method are defined

Comment: So then define them. When they are undefined, the view controller automatically grabs the Xib.

Comment: If he calls `[super loadView]` as shown, then it will still load the NIB.  `[super init]` simply invokes `[self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`.  As a result of passing this nil NIB name, the default implementation of `loadView` will load any NIB found with a base name matching the name of the view controller.  So overriding `init` is unnecessary in this case.  Just eliminate `[super loadView]` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for adding, this will be useful to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own init method. Later if you require the nib you can create a UINib object and when you need the view you can use instantiateWithOwner.

Using `init` when creating your view controller will prevent the nib loading. Another thing to do is to name the nib something other than the name of the view controller - because the nib can be loaded automatically if they match. I use ViewControllerName_iPad or ViewControllerName_iPhone and create the view required depending on device idiom.

Answer (score 0):

The code to load from the xib file is not in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller itself.

You should usually find it in the application delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, or in the info.plist file, under the `NSMainNibFile` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree here, but is the UIViewController loading its view from a XIB because the XIB that loads the UIViewController itself has a "NIB Name" set in the view controller's settings?

e.g. load up MainWindow.xib, see your view controller. Select it, then look in the view controller settings over on the right (4th tab). One of the settings is "NIB Name". Just make that blank to stop the view controller loading its view from that XIB/NIB.